# safe html filtering with php?

Tags: php, html, filter

```
function validCleanHtml( $unclosedString )
{
    preg_match_all( "/<([^\/]\w*)>/", $closedString = $unclosedString, $tags );
    for ( $i = count( $tags[1] ) - 1; $i >= 0; $i-- )
    {
        $tag = $tags[1][$i];
        if ( substr_count( $closedString, "</$tag>" ) < substr_count( $closedString, "<$tag>" ) )
            $closedString .= "</$tag>";
    }
    $validTags = "<em><strong>";
    $validClosedString = strip_tags( $closedString, $validTags );
    return $validClosedString;

}
```

ok what i want is to enable 2 html, em and strong, is this just secure from xss ? if not how can we secure it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `strip_tags` holds the answer.

https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Rather than enabling certain fields, you could also remove the ones you don't want. Namely: `link`, `style`, `script`, `iframe`, `frame`

Comment: @Adam, please consider @jasonbar's answer as well.  It provides [superior filtering options](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#striptags) than `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 12):

Have you looked at any existing solutions like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)? You really don't want to write your own HTML parser - and certainly not with regular expressions.

Comment: I think something like this is the way to go for safehtml.  I don't think it is necessary to re-invent the wheel.  This is exactly what I was looking for, even though it may not be exactly what the original poster of this question was looking for.